# Rails filter records has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I am trying to search an Item model with a filter named genres that are connected by has_many through.

My problem is when I select two genres or more, it also selects records that contain only one genre.

Example: There are two genres named Action and Adventure. Record A has the Action genre and Record B has both genres. By selecting both the genre checkboxs in my view, the records returned by Rails include both Record A & B while it should have only been Record B.

This is my filter statement under the controller

```
  //This is under controller
  @item = Item.includes(:genres).where('genres.id' => params['genre_ids'])
  // This is under my view
  <%= simple_form_for Item.new, :method => :get, url: search_path do |f| %>

        <% Genre.all.each do |sc| %>
            <div>
                <label>
              <%= check_box_tag 'genre_ids[]',sc.id %>
                <span style="font-weight:normal;"><%= sc.name %> </span>
             </label>
            </div>
          <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is in the SQL that is being created from your expression. `where('genres.id' => [1, 2, 3])` gives you `SELECT ... WHERE genres.id IN (1,2,3)` which is essentially OR-expression.

To fix this, you need to filter the number of selected genres in Ruby or SQL. I would do it with SQL like this:

```
genre_ids = params['genre_ids']
items = Item.joins(:genres).where('genres.id' => genre_ids).group('items.id').having("count(*) = #{genre_ids.size}")
```

With this, you will select items with the exact given set of genres. Remember to handle the case with empty `genre_ids` in the parameters.

Comment: I can't test the code right now but for future references about SQL,(I am using PostgresSQL) where can I read up about those common expressions that are commonly used to filter records ?

Comment: What do you mean by "common expressions"? This is just a bit of logic involved -- since you get a record per genre (yes, per genre, not item) in result, you group them by item ID and then remove those with number of records less than the number of genre IDs you provided. This way you get the records with exact set of genres only.